# Array is reassigning previous values into unset locations, PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create a multidimensional array at run-time that queries and stores several MySQL results. For instance, let us say we have a table like so (is fictional, so please don't pick at the example):

```
**store--tag--color--size**
1--101--blue--s
2--102--red--s
2--103--yellow -- m
3--104--blue--m
```

The need is to create an multi-d array that will store all the products per store. The result I would like is:

```
$storeArray = array[[[101],[blue],[s]],[[102,103],[red,yellow],[s,m]],[[104],[blue],[m]]];
```

here is the code I have:

```
$counter = 0;
foreach($storeIDs as $item){
   $result = mysql_query('select whatever');
   $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
   for($i=0;$i<$rows;$i++){
      $tag[$i]       = mysql_result(); 
      $color[$i]     = mysql_result(); 
      $size[$i] = mysql_result(); 
  }
$tempArray = array($tag,$,$color,$size);
$storeArray[$counter] = $tempArray;
unset($tempArray);
$counter++;
}
```

The problem is, even though I have unset $tempArray, the third loop which should capture just

> [[104],[blue],[m]]

actually stores

> [[104,103],[blue,yellow],[m,m]].

I've tried setting $tempArray to array(), or array(array()). The data from the second loop always spills over into ANY future iteration that is of smaller size.

How can I get $storeArray to look like the goal above?

Thank you

Comment: Why shouldn't they? Your inner `for()` loop iterates over the ENTIRE query result set and stuffs the data into $tag/color/size in one fell swoop, and then after you've fetched the data, you build $tempArray.

Comment: There's some code smell here. You are iterating over `$storeArray` **and** modifying it in the loop.

Comment: Have you considered using an associative array to store your information more clearly?

Comment: Right, $tempArray catches the whole inner for() into a 2-d array, which then needs to be packaged into the overall $storeArray. The problem occurs when the query results return less rows on a later iteration. $tempArray should simply have small arrays within it when there are less SQL results, but it actually keeps the highest count and populates the locations with the previous SQL query

Comment: Are you wedded to this weird data structure? Your output basically breaks up the products into parallel arrays of tag, color, and size, instead of a more normal method of keeping each product as a sub-array unit, the parent of which is an array of the store.  This leaves you having to rely on array indices to match up the properties of a product, in a way that is very unusual in PHP (where associative arrays are most commonly used with simple `foreach` loops)

Comment: @Micahel, I realize that the example seems really strange here. The actual use requires it however (and has nothing to do with products).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're unsetting $tmpArray, but it looks like you may need to also unset $tag, $color, and $size as well.  There are better approaches with a slightly different data structure, but as is, have you tried this?

```
unset($tempArray,$tag,$color,$size);
```

Effectively, you might set $tag[0] and $tag[1] in a loop that has two items.  Then, for a loop that has one item you update $tag[0], but $tag[1] remains set.

Comment: Good news, glad to help!